# Is it possible to block merge request that have commit behind in gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, commit

In gitlab, I'd like to block merge request when the requested branch has some commit behind. So that the requester have to merge/rebase again (+ test)

Is it possible to configure gitlab to enforce that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature exist but only in the entreprise edition:
https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/fast_forward_merge.html

To achieve this, set the `merge method` to `Fast-forward merge`: gitlab won't create merge commit and thus the branch to merge should contain all commit of the destination branch